# How did they make Captain America so tiny and skinny in the first half?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, effects, captain-america-the-first-avenger

How did they make Chris Evans so tiny and *skinny* in the first half? He lost weight + green screen all along I suppose? Or is there something more interesting.

Comment: He "burned" off the weight when he was in the Fantastic Four.

Comment: Somewhat related question .... http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/did-spiderman-filming-halt-so-tobey-maguire-could-bulk-up

Comment: Thom Law from Lucky Dusa also played a body double

Comment: If you look carefully at all the evidence around the fact that a big, muscular man could look like a tiny, weak, thin man. The reason this happens is because technology is very advance now so the studio can easily use green screens and they can edit whats he looks like with computers.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[**Lola VFX**](http://www.imdb.com/company/co0129378/) worked on the body transformation of Chris Evans.

From the article **[How to make a Captain America wimp](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/case-study-how-to-make-a-captain-america-wimp/)**

> Lola had three primary approaches to shrinking the 220 pound Evans to the 140 pound guy he needed to be, while maintaining Evans’ performance as closely as possible.
>
> 1. **Body double / actor doubling for the entire body.** *The body double was English Shakespearean trained stage actor [Leander
>      Deeny](http://www.thewrap.com/movies/article/meet-captain-americas-skinny-steve-rogers-leander-deeny-29756) (who even dieted for the role).*
> 2. **Digital head replacement / face projection** – *similar to the technique Lola used in The Social Network, where the actor is filmed
>      with multiple cameras and this digital file is object tracked onto a
>      body double’s (Deeny) body. This was only used in about 5%
>      of Lola’s shots.*
>
>    [image: 2a]
>
>    [image: 2b]
> 3. **Shrink and scale the actor in the principal photography (no greenscreen)** – *a 2D scale of the actor Chris Evans. This was used
>      in the majority – about 85% of Lola’s effects shots.*
>
>    [image: 1a]
>
>    [image: 1b]

Click the link above and read the full article if you want to learn more.

Comment: You can tell that his head looks too big for his body.

Comment: @Zikato: Lots of short, skinny people look like their head is too big for their body.

Comment: Amusingly, this means everyone had to make eye contact with his nipples for the first chunk of the film.

Answer (score 4):

It's all CGI. Chris Evans is large in life. Watch the film in HD ... you can see it looks *smeared* (don't know how to describe it). There is no other way to make Evans look small. He is *not* going to lose weight before or after the main portions of the role are shot to have them do it differently.

Comment: More details here: http://splashpage.mtv.com/2011/07/21/captain-america-chris-evans-skinny-steve/