# Did Robert Downey Jr starve himself for Avengers: Endgame or was it CGI?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony & Nebula are stuck on Titan and later on the Guardians's spaceship, running out of food and water. During the scene in which he records a message to Pepper and when Nebula puts him on the chair, he looks frail and starving with veins popping and blood shot eyes.

When he returns to earth and has a confrontation with Steve Rogers, he really looks weak and fragile. His face and body looks shrunken from the starvation.

Did RDJ starve himself for this part of the role or was it CGI?

I assume it is easier to make Hemsworth fat by using padding but I don't know how/if CGI can make RDJ look skinny and starved.

Comment: I really hope that's some sort of CGI

Answer (score 11):

CGI. IF they used CGI to create "weak" Steve Rogers there is no reason to not use the same technology few year later.
And they already had his facial structure in computer when they "de-younger" him for Civil War.

AND they already did "Tony Stark look" during Iron Man 3 when they used body double to film action scenes when RDJ had an injury and couldn't perform them himself.

Comment: I think weak Steve was another actor. That is what I remember reading

Comment: @KharoBangdo Yes, it was a different actor with Evans face imposed. Same as RDJ in Iron Man 3. That's why it's much more plausible they done this again rather than try to starve RDJ who, in turn, is well known for constantly eating, even during filming.

Comment: [How did they make Captain America so tiny and skinny in the first half?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15941/how-did-they-make-captain-america-so-tiny-and-skinny-in-the-first-half)

Answer (score 3):

In the bonus material from *Avengers: Endgame*, the Russo brothers talk about this scene. They say it was made by the VFX team.

So no, he didn't starve himself.

Comment: Nice find. If you could [edit] in a clip or a quote, that would make for an even better post.

Answer (score -3):

That was a straight up CGI and is also he was made to lose a bit of his weight to make him look a bit week till that part in the movie. 
also, his eyes were made blur and bloody by adding something called Makeup for eyes that's how all these singers keep their eyes the same in all songs except the Adam Lambert he usees Makeup to make them different in all situations

Comment: "Make-up for eyes"? Could you elaborate on that? I don't see how Adam Lambert has anything to do with this question.

Comment: Makeup for eyes include contact lances or in this case, they re-designed the whole thing to look the way did also Adam Lambert is one who has constantly used contact lances and his videos and has a history of damaging eyes with them

Comment: Can you provide a source saying that Robert Downey Jr was wearing contact lenses in that scene, or is this just an assumption? Answers here work better if they have evidence to back them up.

Comment: I tried to look it up on Google but can not find anything but here is a thing, one day I saw a vid form Screen Rant that specifically talked about how CGI can be made better if actors are willing to wear contact lances, so wearing contact lances may have improved the CGI