# The first movie or TV show that said "nerds" were cool

Tags: first-appearance, the-big-bang-theory

Nowadays, the term *nerd* is almost a compliment. It suggests someone, male or female, who has an intense interest in a specific sphere. The most common is *a computer nerd* but I also hear people bragging: "I'm a grammar nerd".

As a matter of fact, someone who might be described as a *student nerd*, suggests a young person who actually enjoys studying rather than someone who is bullied and made to feel like outcast.

The TV sitcom, *The Big Bang Theory*, is often credited for making *nerds* cool. But were they they the first American TV show  to do so?

Here is a YouTube clip (2009) where John Hodgman defines President Obama as being the first nerd president of the modern era.

- **Which TV show, or movie, *first* depicted nerds (using that term) as being intelligent, and "cool"  and not exclusively social outcasts, or embarrassing misfits?**

Comment: Should *Revenge of the Nerds* be mentioned or is that too on the nose? ;) Didn't it and *WarGames* get the ball rolling in 1983-1984?

Comment: This seems slightly primarily-opinion based to me, because it may be hard to objectively decide whether in a given movie nerds are being depicted _as being (super) intelligent and fun to hang out with_.

Comment: Well, it's not *that* unclear really, but it provides some points that might make it a little broad, first and foremost the fact that what a "nerd" is doesn't seem (to me at least) that easily and exactly definable as you pose it, which is also shown by one fo the answers explicitly referencing hackers, which you just ruled out. But if you really want the term "nerd" to be used in the movie, then that might be worth adding into the question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Well, I'm looking at "nerd culture," not geeks, nor hackers. So, yes the term "nerd" must be referred in the movie or TV show. Is my question so unclear? I mean, I'm talking about "nerds", I've given examples of usage, meaning, and I've suggested TBBT as being the prototype show which showed "nerds" in a positive light. If "nerds" are implied in any earlier movie or TV show, that would be "good enough", I suppose.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson would you disagree that the term *hackers* was once something to be proud of? Nowadays it's synonymous with stealing data. A nerd is not the same as a hacker, but if you can persuade me it is, then fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I simply don't know, since the term "nerd" has always been rather fuzzy to me. I also don't really have any interest in one way or the other, let alone in answering the question. I'm just trying to understand it better and cover all the possible arguments for being "primarily opinion-based" or "too broad". But I don't want to make you ask a question you don't want to ask. I'm just trying to incite a useful discussion that might lead to people understanding your question better.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson   POB and too broad?! The answer may very well be TBBT, I'm fine with that too. I just wanted to double check that there were no earlier movies etc. that showed nerds as being heros, e.g. Peter Parker in Spiderman, that sort of thing. P.Parker  was a [***nerd student***](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/did-spiderman-filming-halt-so-tobey-maguire-could-bulk-up/1981#1981), wasn't he?

Comment: I agree that the TBBT nerds are depicted as _"social outcasts and embarrassing misfits"_, but in what way are they shown to be _"cool"_? - __[Happy Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Days)__ (1974-1984) is often credited as the TV show [that popularized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerd#Etymology) the term "Nerd".  In [one episode](http://www.tv.com/shows/happy-days/fonzie-versus-the-she-devils-20635/) Fonzie defends nerds with the words _"Live and let live"_. Does that count?

Comment: @Oliver_C  I think in the US it's become "cooler" to be a bookworm, to be someone who is into science, technology and any subject which requires passion. Nerds, supposedly, have passion, and they care passionately and obsessively about the things that interest them. That kind of in depth knowledge has become "cool". But YMMV

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'd say nerds are looked less down upon today because technology has become ubiquitous. Nowadays people who _don't_ know how to operate a computer or a smart phone are considered "weird". - The characters on TBBT aren't depicted as "cool" though, they even have problems connecting with other nerds, scientist and celebrities nerds like (e.g. Stan Lee, Brent Spiner, Summer Glau, Mike Massimino, George Smoot, Neil deGrasse Tyson,...).

Comment: P.S.: I grew up watching __[MacGyver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver)__ (1985-1992) and he is someone I would feel comfortable calling a "cool nerd".

Comment: *"Nowadays, the term nerd is almost a compliment"* - [citation seriously needed] I still get called a nerd for my interests and profession, and it rarely feels like its meant in a nice way.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Do you think Barack Obama was offended when John Hodgman called him a nerd? Can you imagine anyone calling Donald Trump a nerd? You need brains,  and a hobby taken to an almost zealous level  before the title of nerd can be awarded.

Comment: In my experience "nerd" is never meant as a positive, if Barack Obama was called a nerd it was more than likely intended such that "he is a great individual, even though he is a nerd".

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Times they are a-changin', Maybe in your neck of the woods it's taking longer for the news to arrive. It's definitely hasn't got the "loser" tag which it once had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd have to go with [*Square Pegs* (1982-1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083482/), which featured Sarah Jessica Parker, Jamie Gertz and Traci Nelson (daughter of Rick Nelson of Ozzie and Harriet fame).  Several guest stars included Bill Murray, John Densmore (of The Doors), Mark and Robert Mothersbaugh (of Devo) and Martin Mull.

Sarah Jessica Parker was really the focus of the show, which was about a group of nerdy kids who wanted to be cool.  But, since the focus was on them, you became sympathetic to the nerds and realized they were kinda cool.

Comment: Great answer.  I was going to post Revenge of the Nerds b/c I'd forgotten this show and that it predates that movie by a couple of years.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to go with [**Real Genius**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089886/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_91) (1985)

> Mitch is one of the youngest students ever accepted to a university known for its programs for geniuses. He's partnered up with his roommate, science club legend Chris Knight, on a project to develop a high-powered laser. Together with their hyper-kinetic friends, they employ their intellects in the pursuit of bigger blasts, practical jokes, and a deeper understanding of what real genius is. When their final, functional laser is stolen by their teacher for a military weapon, they decide to get even.

Comment: Were Mitch and Chris Knight ever called "nerds" in the movie?

Comment: I'd have to watch it again to be sure but I'm not sure the actual **word** is that important...more the archetype.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need to rewatch it, just find the script online and scan it for "nerd" or "nerdy". I'll accept references to "geek", nerds and geeks seem to be more interchangeable with one another.

Answer (score 1):

'Nerd' is still not a compliment, afaik. Some people may use it in a non-derogatory manner, but I've never seen someone actually complimenting someone else by saying 'Jeez, you're such a nerd!'. But, granted, that certainly depends on which circles we hang out.

Anyway, the movie '[Hackers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113243/?ref_=nv_sr_1)', from 1995, comes to mind as the oldest movie I know where 'computer nerds' (or more specifically, hackers) are shown as an elite society, smarter than the average.

> Mooo

Comment: Check how [The Plague](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0162649/?ref_=tt_cl_t7) describes average non-hacker people in the video

Comment: OK, cattle, moo. Nowadays I hear "sheep" and "sheeple"  being uttered more frequently. For an upvote, please edit and say when was the movie was released. Thanks

Comment: Actually, if I'm not mistaken, *hackers* were an elite group, it used to be a badge of honour, it meant you were really smart and knew your way around computers. Nowadays, more often than not, it suggests someone dishonest, who cracks secret codes.  I'm not sure if this answer is pertinent. But +1 for stating 1995.